# Tokens being generated after ID delete FCM iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to delete FCM tokens when a user logs out.

I have set `FirebaseMessagingAutoInitEnabled = NO` in my `info.plist`

When I run :

```
instance.deleteID { (error) in
    debugPrint("AFTER Token :- \(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)")
}
```

The print out is nil, as I would expect, but then a few seconds the delegate method `didReceiveRegistrationToken` fires off, and I have a new token again.

I want to explicitly call to delete or generate tokens.

I know the default behavior is to regenerate a new token when an ID is deleted, but with "autoInit" disabled, it is my understanding that tokens should no longer be automatically generated.

How can I stop generating tokens after deleting my FCM Instance?

Comment: Hmmm... I've never done this myself, but from reading the docs what you did should work. Can you show precisely what you've put in your `Info.plist`?